# I can't find a plane I bought

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I paid for a plane but can't find it.  What do I do to get it or find it? I tried to call for it but it doesn't come and it doesn't show up on my map.

Comment: Hm. I don't know why this is closed. I understand your question... To buy a plane you need a hangar. Then buy your plain. After some time, there comes a mail that the plain is delivered. So go to the hangar and you can chose it.

Comment: Who exactly did you call for your plane? You can't call for a plane in GTA V as far as I'm aware.

Comment: all new cars bought go to the garage, in the same sense i expect all flights bought should go to Hangar. Look for the hangar icon on the map and proceed to see if you can find it there.

Answer (score 4):

Your plane will be at the **hangar of the airfield you bought**.  If it has not showed up yet, it may just take some time.  I have heard users experiencing waiting times from 10 minutes to 3 hours before it showed up.

If you have multiple planes or helicopters in your hangar, you can switch them before entering the vehicle.  Just walk up to the helicopter or plane and the option to switch current helicopter/plane will appear.

**Try looking at the Sandy Shores Airfield**:

[image]